# Array and action listener java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Really appreciated the help on the last question, still have a couple of errors however. I am making a treasure Hunt game where the user  clicks on a gui to try and reveal the location of a treasure chest. I was using an action listener to display a image of a treasure chest on the button if the location was found but that was a fixed position and I wanted to randomise this. Got some advice to use an array on buttons and random number generator then use an if/else to check. Having complier errors which I will comment on the code below. A good coder will probably pick my novice errors up in a matter of seconds!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;



  public class Test extends JFrame {


     JLabel label1, label2, label3;    

    ImageIcon image1, image2, image3, image4, image5;


 JTextField textResult;    

  public static void main(String[] args) {



  new Test();

    }


   public Test (){

  this.setSize(700,700);
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setTitle("Treasure Hunt Game");

  JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();


  thePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,0,0));

  image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Treasure.jpg"));
  image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pirate.jpg"));
  image3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sand2.jpg"));
  image4 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("emptyhole.jpg"));   
  image5 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("map.jpg"));

  label1 = new JLabel("Click the buttons to find the Treasure!");
  label2 = new JLabel(image5); 
  label3 = new JLabel(image2);


  JButton [] buttons = new JButton[9]; 
  buttons[0] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[1] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[2] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[3] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[4] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[5] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[6] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[7] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[8] = new JButton(image3);


  thePanel.add(buttons[0]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[1]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[2]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[3]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[4]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[5]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[6]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[7]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[8]);
  thePanel.add(label1); 
  thePanel.add(label2);
  thePanel.add(label3);



  this.add(thePanel);

  this.setVisible(true);


  int treasureLocation = new Random().nextInt(buttons.length);


  System.out.println(treasureLocation);
```

On the complier, it gives me a error message saying it does not know the "buttons"  or "treasureLocation" in the if else statement below.

```
        }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      if (evt.getSource() == buttons[treasureLocation]) {
      }

  else {

  }

  } 

}
```

Comment: Does it print the statement?

Comment: Please show more code, at least the location of the `actionPerformed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JLabel label1, label2, label3;    
ImageIcon image1, image2, image3, image4, image5;
JTextField textResult;
JButton [] buttons; // Move the declaration here
int treasureLocation; // Move the declaration here
```

and change

```
JButton [] buttons = new JButton[9];
```

to

```
buttons = new JButton[9];
```

and

```
int treasureLocation = new Random().nextInt(buttons.length);
```

to

```
treasureLocation = new Random().nextInt(buttons.length);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help Ajai. It seems to of sorted out the problem. I have encounter a new problem which you may be of assistance? I've got working so it randomly generates the picture of chest on the button when clicked through the if statement, which is great. However, any ideas how I could change the picture on the other buttons so when they are clicked they change to an empty hole? I thought an if else statement but not sure how to do this. I'll make an new question with the code on it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have a different Listener class?

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test(){
        Button[] buttons;
        int treasureLocation;
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (evt.getSource() == buttons[treasureLocation]) {
        }
    }
}
```

This would cause an error as `buttons` and `treasureLocation` are not within the scope. If this is not the case, it still seems like a scope issue to me. Try declaring the variables as class members

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    Button[] buttons;
    int treasureLocation;

    public Test(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. It seems to of sorted out the problem. I have encounter a new problem which you may be of assistance? I've got working so it randomly generates the picture of chest on the button when clicked through the if statement, which is great. However, any ideas how I could change the picture on the other buttons so when they are clicked they change to an empty hole? I thought an if else statement but not sure how to do this. I'll make an new question with the code on it.

Answer (score 0):

You actually defined `buttons` and `treasureLocation` in your constructor, which is actually `not` recommended. Their lifecycle and access is therefore limited to this method. Define them in your class and initialize them.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help Ben. It seems to of sorted out the problem. I have encounter a new problem which you may be of assistance? I've got working so it randomly generates the picture of chest on the button when clicked through the if statement, which is great. However, any ideas how I could change the picture on the other buttons so when they are clicked they change to an empty hole? I thought an if else statement but not sure how to do this. I'll make an new question with the code on it.

Comment: Yes, create a new question for that. If I find the time I will look it up!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `buttons` and `treasureLocation` defined as attributes.  So don't define them in a method or a constructor, have them defined in the line after

`ImageIcon image1, image2, image3, image4, image5;`